# I need to make it so that when you catch all the letters of the word, write "End" and stop the game.(Python)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I need to do that when you catch all the falling letters of the word,
write "End" and stop the game. And if you catch the wrong letter (which is not in word) it should take one of the already caught ones from word. Ex.(word is vasara) if you have caught 'V' and than Y it should take away V.     (Python)

```
from turtle import *
from random import *


ABC = u'ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPRSTVZ'
word = u"vasara".upper()
chached_letters = []
la = 1

P = Turtle()
P.hideturtle()

def info():
  hideturtle()
  speed(0);   penup();   color("grey")
  goto(-200, -180); pendown(); forward(400); penup() 
  goto(-180, -200)
  
  for letter in word:
    if letter in chached_letters:
      color('blue')
    else:
      color('grey')
    write( letter, font=("Arial", 18))
    forward(20)

    


        
info()

screen = getscreen()

drops = [] 
for k in range(10): 

    new = Turtle()
    drops.append(new)
    new.speed(0)
    new.penup()
    x = -200 + k*35 
    y = randint(100, 200)
    new.goto(x, y)
    new.color('blue')
    new.setheading(-90)
    new.hideturtle()
    new.step = randint(2, 6)
    new.letter = choice( ABC )
    new.write( new.letter, font = ("Arial", 18) )


def spust(x, y):
    for drop in drops:
        Lx = drop.xcor()
        Ly = drop.ycor()

        if Lx < x < Lx+20 and Ly < y < Ly+20:                                               
           chached_letters.append( drop.letter )
           drop.sety(200)
           drop.letter = choice( ABC )
           info()

screen.onclick(spust)



screen.tracer(0) 
while True: 
    for drop in drops:
        drop.forward( drop.step )
        drop.clear()
        drop.write( drop.letter, font = ("Arial", 18) )

        if drop.ycor() < -180:
            drop.sety(200)
            drop.letter = choice (ABC)
    screen.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reworked your code below adding the two features you describe.  I've changed `caught_letters` (nee `cached_letters`) from a `list` to a `set` to simplify the logic.  I've tossed your `while True:`, which has no place in an event-driven world like turtle, replacing it with an `ontimer()` event:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice, randint
from string import ascii_uppercase as ABC

FONT = ("Arial", 18, 'normal')
BIGFONT = ("Arial", 36, 'bold')

word = "vasara".upper()
word_letters = set(word)

def info():
    turtle.goto(-180, -200)

    for letter in word:
        turtle.color('blue' if letter in caught_letters else 'grey')
        turtle.write(letter, font=FONT)
        turtle.forward(20)

def spust(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None)  # disable handler inside handler

    for drop in drops:
        if drop.distance(x, y) < 20:
            if drop.letter in word:
                caught_letters.add(drop.letter)
            elif caught_letters:
                # if you catch a wrong letter (which is not in word)
                # it should take one of the already caught ones from word
                caught_letters.pop()

            drop.letter = None
            break

    info()
    screen.onclick(spust)  # reenable handler

def running():
    for drop in drops:
        drop.forward(drop.step)

        if drop.letter is None or drop.ycor() < -180:
            drop.sety(200)
            drop.letter = choice(ABC)

        drop.clear()
        drop.write(drop.letter, font=FONT)

    if word_letters == caught_letters:
        # when you catch all the falling letters of
        # the word, write "End" and stop the game.
        screen.onclick(None)
        marker.home()
        marker.write("End", align='center', font=BIGFONT)
    else:
        screen.ontimer(running, 75)  # milliseconds

    screen.update()

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(0)

marker = Turtle()
marker.hideturtle()
marker.speed('fastest')
marker.color("grey")
marker.penup()
marker.goto(-200, -180)
marker.pendown()
marker.forward(400)
marker.penup()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

caught_letters = set()

info()

drops = []

for k in range(10):
    new = Turtle()
    new.hideturtle()
    new.speed('fastest')
    new.color('blue')
    new.setheading(-90)

    new.penup()
    x = -200 + k*35
    y = randint(100, 200)
    new.goto(x, y)

    new.step = randint(3, 6)
    new.letter = choice(ABC)
    new.write(new.letter, font=FONT)

    drops.append(new)

screen.onclick(spust)

running()

screen.mainloop()
```

I rearranged the code to minimize what happens in the main loop (i.e. less drawing.)  Cute game!